# Why am I getting HTTP 404 on all controllers I copied into a new MVC4 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a new MVC4 project, as I had messed around with too many default, templated content in the one I was working on. I set Authentication to 'None', and copied quite a few components, e.g. controllers, base classes, view models, validators (Fluent Validation) etc. over. I kept the original `Home` controller and view.

That original `Home` page, through its `Index` action, is all that works. All my 'imported' controllers derive from `ComairRIController`, while `Home` doesn't, but I even tried removing this inheritance from one of my controllers and just inheriting from `Controller`, just like `Home`, with no effect; I still get the 404.

The project builds with no errors or warnings at all and runs fine opening the Home/Index view. What could be wrong here? How can I diagnose this? The constructor for my `ComairRIController` doesn't even get invoked, so the request isn't getting very far at all.

I am using the default route configuration:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**IMPORTANT INFORMATION:** Both the source project (pure MVC4) and destination project (Orchard module) have exactly the same names, and default namespaces. I intentionally did this to avoid as many namespace mismatches as possible.

**NEW INFORMATION:** I have added Elmah 2.0.2 via NuGet, and set it up to log to XML files. It logs an error for each 404, the error being (I have omitted the stack trace for brevity):

```
<error errorId="db2b4236-b913-4b98-878e-f3e02fdff321" 
    application="/" 
    host="7F3KH5J" 
    type="System.Web.HttpException" \
    message="The controller for path '/ApplicantProfile/Start' was not found or does not implement IController." 
    source="System.Web.Mvc" 
    detail="System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/ApplicantProfile/Start' was not found or does not implement IController.&#xD;&#xA;
```

Interestingly, requests for Elmah.axd also return a 404.

Comment: How does your routes look like?

Comment: can you post a sample view and controller that you are working with?

Comment: Again I'd request that you review your namespaces and folders that contain your controllers.  I've encountered this exact issue before, and it was due to the fact my controllers were contained in Areas or additional folders.  Review your working Home controller, and the namespaces for each.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you copied over a few components from an existing project, but didn't mention whether or not you copied over the Views for anything except the Home/Index action.

Could it be there's no matching view for any of your other Controllers?

Comment: I said I "copied quite a few components, e.g. controllers, base classes, view models, validators (Fluent Validation) etc. over". Everything is where it should be.

Comment: Without seeing the code contained in the failing controllers this is hard to diagnose.  Having copied multiple items from a separate project, I'd advise that you double-check the namespaces for the imported controllers.